# How to show only latest value in influx-db&Grafana?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql

I am trying to run a dashboard with **influxdb** and **grafana** and i would like to show only the latest values of each `id` e.g. if i have a table something like this

| id | utime |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 9:10AM |
| 3 | 9:20AM |
| 2 | 9:30AM |
| 2 | 9:35AM |
| 4 | 9:40AM |
| 4 | 9:50AM |

Now I would like to create a query in which it will only show me the latest result of each `id` and the result will show something like this below..

```
| 2    | 9:35AM            |
| 3    | 9:20AM            |
| 4    | 9:50AM            |
```

I am new to this and don't know how exactly will it work. I have tried this query below but it didn't worked.

```
SELECT "id", "utime" FROM "http_listener_v2" WHERE $timeFilter  GROUP BY "id"
```

Can somebody please help,how can I do this?

Comment: BTW: `InfluxQL` != `SQL`. InfluxQL offers `LAST()` - https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#last , but you it needs field (not a tag). Of course you need also GROUP BY id.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I solved it by using id as a tag..